# Eventlistener Inside EventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I have a code that runs inside freshsales iframe. My application code inside iframe is placed inside iframe load event listener. So my javascript application starts after application window is loaded. Long story short: my application runs inside an event listener.

But problem occurs when I reload page without refresh (I dont make refresh, I just jump from one tab to another tab and when I open the tab that my app works, "app.activated" event fires and so my javascript application starts. Every thing is good till now. But when I went to another tab and come to my tab again, event listeners attached to my app created again ( Just my hyphothesis) and because of this every time, I jump back to my app, a new event listener atttached to same object. So when I click the the related object more than 1 event is fired and related function runs more than 1 time.

Here I attach the code:

```
var client;
$(document).ready( function() {
    app.initialized()
        .then(function(_client) {
            client = _client;
            client.events.on("app.activated",
                function() {
                    console.log("APP LOADED");

                    //These are event listener functions that fires 2 or more times when app is loaded more than 1 time
                    let nextButtonScript = function(){
                        getReportDataAndFill(  );
                    } 
                    let prevButtonScript = function(){
                      getReportDataAndFill(  );
                    }

                    //I added these lines to prevent double attachment of event listener to same object, but that didnt helped
                    document.getElementById("skvPrevMonth").removeEventListener("click", prevButtonScript);
                    document.getElementById("skvNextMonth").removeEventListener("click", nextButtonScript);
                    //I add event listener to elements here
                    document.getElementById("skvPrevMonth").addEventListener("click", prevButtonScript);
                    document.getElementById("skvNextMonth").addEventListener("click", nextButtonScript);
                });
        });
});
```

SO again to sum up, when I run this code and when I jump to another tab and come to my app tab again (which fires "app.activated" event), then when I click "skvPrevMonth" button, its event listener function fires 2 times. If I again jump another tab and come again then it fires 3 times and so on....

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Just make a variable like `listenersAdded`. Set it to true when `app.initialized()` first runs, then only add the listeners if that variable is false.

Comment: I tried adding variable as a flag but this doesnt work. I think it is because a different variable is created each time main callback is run

Comment: Make it a global variable

Comment: This worked thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions `nextButtonScript` and `prevButtonScript` are being defined inside the `app.activated` callback. That means every time that callback is run, those variables hold references to *different functions*, not the same ones. That's why it's not removing the old listeners: because you're telling it to remove the current functions but those haven't been added yet. The old ones, with their different references, remain.

Define those two functions outside the scope of your callback (they don't seem to be using any variables that need the inner scope anyway) and it should work, since the references will remain constant across event firings :)

Comment: I think this should work but I simplified the code. Infact each of them need lots of inner variables. So moving function outside will not be that easy. Anyway thanks for good idea. ANd really thanks for good explanation. Yes it is like creating new object every time and its inner variables created differently for each object. You are right!